# Images not getting displayed in laravel blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to display multiple images from public folder to laravel blade view. But its not getting displayed.

Here is my view code.

```
<div class="card-body">
  <table class="table">
   <thead>
     <th>Image</th>
     <th>Title</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach($posts as $post)
       <tr>
         <td><img src="{{asset($post->image)}}" width="60px" height="60px" alt=""></td>
         <td>{{$post->title}}</td>
       </tr>
      @endforeach
   </tbody>

  </table>

</div>
```

Its anyway showing title. I thought it may be an issue with url so i tried possible urls to see the image. But this is the most accurate one

```
<td><img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/TNL0RZhSi0zkmdBS3IAZodv0dqNEeVT4LbJ6GJk2.jpeg" width="60px" height="60px" alt=""></td>
```

So most possibly the issue is Public folder is not accessble. But i have tried `pup artisan storage:link` Itried every possible answer in SO,but no luck

*Laravel Framework 5.8.38*

Comment: Can you try to echo the `{{asset($post->image)}}` to see what url are the function returning? `php artisan storage:link` is used to create a symbolic link in your public directory to your storage folder, so it won't solve your case.

Comment: @KayLun yes i tried that and it properly showed the image path as "posts/TNL0RZhSi0zkmdBS3IAZodv0dqNEeVT4LbJ6GJk2.jpeg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image src path has not been properly declared so what you want to do is access the storage folder where the images are stored then render as show below

```
<img src="/storage/folder_name/{{$post->image}}" alt="image">
```

I hope this helps